# Filling date gaps with most recent value

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm developing a script at my company that will pull information from our SCM about source code activity, such as the number of lines changed, for a given product over time. All the changes for a given product that occur within the same day are combined into a single record in a mySQL table, something like this:

```
+------------+-------+------+
| date       | prod  | line |
+------------+-------+------+
| 2011-11-25 | prod2 |  471 |
| 2011-11-28 | prod2 |  389 |
+------------+-------+------+
```

I then replicate the table with the cumulative results using an inner join and summation:

```
+------------+-------+------+
| date       | prod  | line |
+------------+-------+------+
| 2011-11-25 | prod2 |  471 |
| 2011-11-28 | prod2 |  860 |
+------------+-------+------+
```

Now, I want to create a table that has one record for every day per product. I've been able to do that by joining with a calendar table. However, where new records are created, the *line* field should be populated with the most recent cumulative value for that product, rather than some hardcoded default like NULL or 0:

```
+------------+-------+------+
| date       | prod  | line |
+------------+-------+------+
| 2011-11-25 | prod2 |  471 |
| 2011-11-26 | prod2 |  471 |
| 2011-11-27 | prod2 |  471 |
| 2011-11-28 | prod2 |  860 |
+------------+-------+------+
```

I've solved this problem in two unsatisfying ways so far:

1. Fill in the date gaps first, *then* compute the cumulative sum
2. Loop over every element of the final table, saving the most recent non-null elements in a @user variable.

The first solution became hugely inefficient once my table grew large enough. The second solution gets the job done, but I've been trying to find a more elegant solution. Here is the code that produces the table with NULLs:

```
INSERT INTO final SELECT d.date,f.prod,p.line
FROM calendar AS d
CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT prod FROM cumulative) AS f
LEFT JOIN cumulative AS p USING (date,prod) ;
```

Any ideas? I'm using MySQL.

Comment: Why would you be creating not one, but 2 redundant tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the most sensible thing to do would be to store one row per day, with a zero if there were no lines changed.  That would eliminate the need for a join on the calendar table.

So instead of your source table looking like this

```
+------------+-------+------+
| date       | prod  | line |
+------------+-------+------+
| 2011-11-25 | prod2 |  471 |
| 2011-11-28 | prod2 |  389 |
+------------+-------+------+
```

it would look like this.

```
+------------+-------+------+
| date       | prod  | line |
+------------+-------+------+
| 2011-11-25 | prod2 |  471 |
| 2011-11-26 | prod2 |    0 |
| 2011-11-27 | prod2 |    0 |
| 2011-11-28 | prod2 |  389 |
+------------+-------+------+
```

As for the running sum itself, your report writer might be able to do this faster than SQL.  If MySQL supported windowing functions, you'd just write something like

```
select date, prod, 
       sum(line) over (partition by prod order by date)
from prod
```

although, even then, your report writer might be faster.

On platforms that don't support windowing functions, you just need a sum in a subquery.

```
select p1.prod, p1.date, 
       (select sum(line) from prod 
        where prod = p1.prod and date <= p1.date) as num_lines
from prod p1
order by p1.prod, p1.date
```